# Jenkinsfile - spin up laravel by docker-compose and run tests?

Tags: laravel, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm a semi-newb when it comes to CI/CD.  I'm attempting to use our Jenkins instance to spin up a Laravel instance (with php,mysql,testing lib[Dusk],etc baked in).  I can successfully do all the actions locally without jenkins, so I know my app works.  I can also successfully spin up docker-compose in my jenkins instance (judging by the console output).  However, after I successfully spin up via docker-compose (docker-compose up -d), I don't know how to then run the laravel commands within that container.  For example, 'sh 'php artisan make:test UserTest'.  However I'm getting 'php: command not found'  How do I 'enter' the running instance?

Here is most of my jenkinsfile (I've tried running my php commands in the root dir too):

```
pipeline {
agent {
    label 'docker' 
  }
environment {
    APP_NAME='Laravel'
    APP_ENV='local'
    ...etc
}
stages {
    stage("docker & dc -v") {
        steps {
          sh 'docker --version'
          sh 'docker-compose --version'
          sh 'docker-compose up -d'
          sh 'echo "test is coming....."'
          dir('src') {
            sh "pwd"
            sh 'ls -la'
            sh 'php artisan make:test UserTest'
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `docker-compose up`, it will spawn a container for each `service` defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file. If you put `sh 'php artisan make:test UserTest'` in your Jenkins file, it will not execute your command in a container, so you won't have access to your dev/test environment.
Instead, you will need a testing image : a Dockerfile with `php` installed, and your tests file copied into it, so that you can set its `CMD` to `php artisan make:test UserTest`, which will get executed when a container is created from the image built from the Dockerfile.
Then, either add it to your Compose `services`, or start it explicitly with `docker run testing_image`. Then check its exit code, stdout/stderr, files produced to determine how the tests went.